# jQuery : Append to outer tr in a table

Tags: jquery, html

please help me, i'm trying to append element outside the tr of div class addjob and i dont know how to do this.. BTW this how this function work.. whenever i try to click the add jobtitle it must append it outside the tr>td>div.addjob

here is my jquery :

```
         $(function() { 
$('body').on('click','.rmv',function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').hide('slow', function(){  $(this).parents('tr').remove(); });
});

$('body').on('click','.addjob',function(){
        var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();
         console.log($clone);
         $clone.append("<td><div class='rmv' >Remove</div></td>");
         ($(this)).append($clone);  
});


 });
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<table cellspacing="10" class="tbll" >
<tr>
<td>Choose Sub Heading</td><td><select name="subheading_id" style="min-width:145Px">
            <option value="1" Sub heading Me</option>
            <option value="2" Sub heading Me 2</option>     
    </select></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cloneme">
<td>Choose Job Title</td><td><select name="jobtitles_id" style="min-width:145Px"><?php
            <option value="a" >A</option>   
            <option value="b" >B</option>   
            <option value="c" >C</option>       
                    <option value="none" >None</option> 
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="addjob" >Add another Job Title</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "outside" == "before", "after", "somewhere else on the page" ..... ?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to append the cloned `<tr>` to `<div class=addjob>`.. try appending it to the parent()..

try this

```
 $('body').on('click','.addjob',function(){
    var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();
     console.log($clone);
     $clone.append("<td><div class='rmv' >Remove</div></td>");
     $('div.addjob').parents().eq(2).append($clone);   //here
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/tnGt6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.addjob').parent('tr').after($clone);
```

i guess this will do it

full code

```
$('body').on('click','.rmv',function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').hide('slow', function(){  $(this).parents('tr').remove(); });
});

$('body').on('click','.addjob',function(){
        var $clone = $('table.tbll tr.cloneme:first').clone();
         console.log($clone);
         $clone.append("<td><div class='rmv' >Remove</div></td>");
        $('div.addjob').parent('tr').after($clone);
});
```